# Skype causes audio/video playback to speed up?

Tags: 12.04, sound, video, pulseaudio, skype

Recently I had a problem with audio and video playback speeds.  The night before the issue everything played fine (on VLC, Youtube, etc.).  The day after, the audio and video playback speeds were increased to where the audio sounds like high-pitched cartoon characters.

In response, I reinstalled PulseAudio hoping to solve the issue.  However, today I was watching a Youtube video and received a message on Skype.  After receiving the message, the audio and video playbacks increased in speed instantly to the previously mentioned state.

Is this an issue with Skype or possibly PulseAudio?  Does anyone happen to know any solutions to this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Uninstalling Skype resolved the issue.  However I would like a solution that allows me to keep Skype installed.  I often have to make conference calls using Skype and don't want to have to switch OS just to use Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe you may have another program that is messing up the sound in Skype. Skype itself is very buggy for Linux. It is not very well built, in my opinion, from past problems I've had with Skype. You could try to reinstall Skype if you can. I cannot give a very technical answer, but I thought even just trying to help might make  you feel a little better. I hope I helped.